# Connection refused in docker while sending request to another container

Tags: docker

I am running my both program inside docker on local host.

While I send request from one container to another I am getting connection refused  error.

One is running on 8000 port and another one is running on 8001.

I run my image using command `docker run -p 8000:8000 service1` and vice versa.

I am trying to connect service running on 8000 from 8001.

I am getting error like:

`connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: You need docker network to container can talk each other. https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#bridge-networks

Comment: I tried it but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: the -p command is only telling your container to expose the port to your host machine. 
You need to link the 2 containers over a network. Either you can create one and add both the containers on it. Or just add in `--network host` which would add these containers to your localhost network.
Could you post your command how you are creating the 2 containers over the network and how are you sending the requests. It will be helpful.
ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: I am connecting container to network using command 'docker run -p 8000:8000 --network=isolated_network -itd --name=serv1 service1'

Comment: for sending request i am using 127.0.0.1:8000 is that correct or do i have to change it?

Comment: @Akku when  you create nework and join container to that. Please connect via container name instead IP

Comment: @Truong Dang Thanks it works for me.

Comment: Yep. Or incase you want connect via IP. `docker network inspect` then you can see list of containers joined to network. And their IP address. Connect via that IP...

Comment: `localhost` and 127.0.0.1 are basically always wrong in Docker; in a container context they always refer to "this container".  Docker will allow you to use the other service name as a host name and you should use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Docker-Compose with network mode as **Host**

```
 network_mode: "host"
```

Check sample Docker-compose file :-

```
version: '2.1'

services:

#Governing microservices
  api-gateway:
   build: zuul-apigateway/
   depends_on:
    eureka-server:
     condition: service_healthy
   restart: always
   network_mode: "host"
   image: demo-zuul-service
   hostname: localhost
   ports:
    - 9085:9085
   healthcheck:
    test: "exit 0"

  eureka-server:
   build: eureka-server/
   restart: always
   network_mode: "host"
   image: demo-eureka-service
   hostname: localhost
   ports:
    - 9083:9083
   healthcheck:
    test: "exit 0"
```

Now these both containers can communicate with each other As the are in **Host network**

**Referance:-**

https://github.com/thoopalliamar/Juggler/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

This is 13 microservice application which can commnicate with each other.

Comment: To understand docker-compose more clearly refer this document and feel free to as any further  https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Host networking is kind of a hack, especially for basic inter-service communication.  This shouldn't be a preferred path.

Comment: He can use any network i gave him the documentation. Is this want you want to tell or something else?